# Swift OSX Firebase app cannot read data

Tags: swift, firebase

I am trying to create an OSX Swift app with Firebase.  I can write to Firebase following the examples, but is not able to read the data back correctly.   I have tried using the .Value listener and println(snapshot.value), it appears that the value returned is not correct.

```
  let userRoot = "https://inkcloud.firebaseio.com/users/" + user
   ref = Firebase(url:userRoot)
   ref!.observeEventType(.ChildChanged, withBlock: { snapshot in
                let result = snapshot.value.objectForKey("test") as? String
                println("the result is \(result)")
            }, withCancelBlock: { error in
                println(error.description)
        })
```

I get compiler error: '() -> AnyObject!' does not have a member named 'objectForKey'

Any help would be appreciated.

Ben

Answer (score 0):

Found the soluiton, need to use functions calls instead of property.